# How to achieve this glitch text effect in Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: typography, photoshop-effects

I have been searching for how can I create a similar effect to [this](https://www.behance.net/gallery/68954125/Control-explorations-in-glitched-typography). I found that it is known as the glitch effect and could only be achieved by using a scanner, and since I don't have a scanner, I wanted to ask if is there any way to create the same effect using Adobe Photoshop? I have tried using the Pinch, Liquify and Scratches filters, but they did not work.

[image]

Comment: This [Link](https://getflywheel.com/layout/glitch-effect-photoshop-how-to/#:~:text=Open%20the%20image%20you'd,apply%20the%20glitch%20effect%20to.) might help you find your answer.

Comment: While I have no idea how you might achieve that effect with or without a scanner, I feel the need to ask why you don't have one? Can people in your district not buy used scanners for pocket change?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's one possible method . . .

Make sure everything is just one layer - flatten all layers if necessary.

Create a new transparent layer above, and using the Clone tool, Clone little pieces of text somewhat randomly onto this new layer.

Something like this perhaps

[image]

Use the Smudge tool with a textured brush tip to drag across some of the cloned letters

[image]

Finally, change the layer blending mode to Hard Light, or experiment with the various blend modes.

[image]

You could also experiment with different kinds of brush tips for different smudge effects, or add similar extra layers with different blend modes, etc

[image]